# Java software with Client Server RDBMS

Tags: java, sqlite, client-server, rdbms

I am trying to design software with Java that will have a database running on a network connected to a single offline server system (the server is not necessarily connected to the internet)

The network with the server system is already existing, but I need ideas on how best to achieve a solution.

I am quite familiar with embedded databases using SQLite. However, it appears SQLite is not a good fit for client-server databases. There might be concurrent update operations which I think will lock up an SQLite database.

Now my questions are:

- What are the steps involved in achieving this goal?
- How do I know which RDBMS system is best to use in this scenario? I have read about PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL, Microsoft Access and MySQL. I would love something a bit similar to SQLite.
- Must the software be web based or can I make it a desktop app? (I am quite comfortable with the latter).
- The previous software stored its database in a Microsoft Access file located on a shared folder on the server system. How effective is this method? How does it work?
- How is it possible to write software without worrying about the database end? (using something like "abstraction")

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046404/getting-started-with-client-server-networking) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575170/java-client-server-software-multiple-machines) 
but they didn't mention anything about RDBMS.
I also checked [SQLite over a network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008357/sqlite-over-a-network) out because its a bit related to what I want to achieve... but nothing much there. I also saw [Use of sqlite on network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137994/use-of-sqlite-on-network-share) which was quite enlightening too... but I need more info.

Comment: Q1: seems way too broad for Stack Overflow (and what *is* your goal anyway?). Q2: questions for "Which thing is best to use in this scenario?" tend to get closed, but "How can I decide which thing to use?"-type questions might be okay instead. Q3 is a good specific question. Q4 is not a question. Q5 is not a question. (And if you're wondering why I'm not writing an answer, I don't have time right now, which is not to say that someone else won't)

Comment: @immibis thanks for reading my question. i have noted your comment. but i thought i made my goals clear at the beginning of the question. i have rephrased Q1,Q4 and Q5. But please is my question that ambiguous??

Comment: What is the server not necessarily connected to?

Comment: @immibis... sorry i didnt see that omission. the server is not connected to the internet. it is just linked to a local network with upto 6+ computers.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the steps involved in achieving this goal?

Use JDBC. It can connect to remote servers using TCP

> How do I know which RDBMS system is best to use in this scenario?

We can't help you here, but I would use a database *server* as opposed to a file based database like Access or SQLite.

> I would love something a bit similar to SQLite.

SQLite was [written](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-05/what-i-learned-about-sqlite-at-a-postgresql-conference) using PostgreSQL 6.5 docs.

> Must the software be web based or can I make it a desktop app?

It can be a desktop app, made with say Swing or JavaFX

> The previous software stored its database in a Microsoft Access file
>   located on a shared folder on the server system. How effective is this
>   method? How does it work?

No comment.

> How is it possible to write software without worrying about the
>   database end? (using something like "abstraction")

Use an ORM (like Hibernate) and use ANSI SQL where you can.